# Why are floating point numbers rounded automatically in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to assign a certain list position value to a certain value in another list. The value in the second list is `24.199999999999996`. However, when i assign that value to a certain index value in the first list I get the value `24.2`, when I print it. How do I keep the value as it is?

Comment: Use a format specifier that tells it how many fractional digits to print. Otherwise it uses a small default and rounds.

Comment: Could you post your code, and are you assigning the value

Comment: Try, for example, `print '%22.16f' % (value)`. But it's unclear why you want to show all of those decimal places. The actual precision of the answer is probably not that high.

Answer (score 1):

The value is getting rounded when `print`ed for display purposes by default. The actual value in the list does not change. If you actually check it:

```
value == 24.2
```

`False` will be returned.

Comment: @marwagaser As Charif DZ said we would need to see your code to give you a more detailed answer. See [mcve] for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want this printing behaviour you have to round your numbers to a reasonable precision. You can use the built-in function 'round'.

```py
>>> round(1.33333333, 5)
1.33333
```